# Batch Script to copy folder from Server to user desktop in a network

Tags: batch-file, scripting

My goal is to create a batch script to copy a folder with subfolders to user desktop with overwrite option and minimized of command prompt.

I am pushing the script through Group policy in user start up screen.

However I am getting an error when running the script locally. Not sure what I am missing in the script..

```
@echo off
@cls

if not "%minimized%"=="" goto :minimized

set minimized=true

start /min cmd /C "%~dpnx0"

goto :EOF

:minimized
echo Your Source Path:

set INPUT1=\\X.X.X.X\Test\TMS\
echo Your Destination Path:
set INPUT2=C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\

xcopy %INPUT1% %INPUT2% /y /s

:minimized
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Please find the error which I get as below,                                                                               Your Source Path:
Your Destination Path:
Invalid path
0 File(s) copied
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Please [edit] your question to format your code and include the error (also formatted) there. Take the [tour] and learn [ask]. We only accept a [mcve] here. Checkout https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: why are you calling the script from itself? `start /min cmd /C "%~dpnx0"`, you have two `minimized` labels? It is better to use `if not defined` than `if not %..% ==` in this instance. It would be simpler if you simply set a temp drive map instead of full UNC path and alweays enclose paths in double quotes, even if you do not have a space in the path, it eliminates possible whitespace. i.e `set "INPUT2=C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\"`

Comment: Are you wanting to copy the folder TMS itself, or the content of TMS?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned folder, so I am writing this assuming you want to create the TMS folder with content on the desktop.

I would try something like this inside of you minimized label. This is untested as I have no Network drives to test with.

```
for /f "tokens=2" %i in ('net use * "\\X.X.X.X\Test\TMS\" ^| findstr /i Drive') do set "tmpDr=%%i"
  mkdir  "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\TMS" >nul
  xcopy "%tmpDir%\*" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\TMS" /s /y
  net use /d %tmpDir% >nul
```

Some things to note in your code. You have 2 `minimized` labels, you need to enclose path variables with double quotes to eliminate possible whitespace, you can drop the `echo`'s seeing as you plan on running the script minimized. Last but not least, you do not need to specify full path to the user's desktop as `%USERPROFILE%` variable already exists as `Drive:\Users\Username`